# SQL - To find max and min salary from emp table along with emp name?

Tags: sql, postgresql, max, window-functions, min

I need to find max and min salary for each department along with emp name . Below is my sample dataset.
[image]

Expected output is :

[image]

Please share your thoughts on this

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Dept_id,
       MIN(Salary) OVER (PARTITION BY Dept_id) Min_Salary,
       FIRST_VALUE(Emp_Name) OVER (PARTITION BY Dept_id ORDER BY Salary) Min_salary_emp_name,
       MAX(Salary) OVER (PARTITION BY Dept_id) Max_Salary,
       FIRST_VALUE(Emp_Name) OVER (PARTITION BY Dept_id ORDER BY Salary DESC) Max_salary_emp_name
FROM tablename;
```

Comment: Getting error.. Do we need to use group by clause. since analytical function used in select clause

Comment: @LearnHadoop what is the error?

Comment: @LearnHadoop check here: https://dbfiddle.uk/jcB6297m that the query is syntactically correct.

Comment: ERROR:  column "emp.depart_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 2:     distinct depart_id,
                     ^

Comment: @LearnHadoop I'm sure that you did not use my code as it is.